# How to check the internal storage to see if it's ready right after the phone is rebooted?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, filepath, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am creating an app which allows the users to select their images from Gallery and display them as slideshow.

The missing image paths from SQLite Datbase  will be automatically deleted whenever the images are missing, moved, or deleted.  It makes sure the SD Card (External Storage) is mounted before deleting any image path.
Everything works fine **except for the phones with the internal and external storage SWAPPED**.

For example,

My phone external storage (SD card) is treated as internal storage, 
and

internal storage is treated as external storage.

Therefore, whenever the phone is rebooted, the app just deletes all the image paths off the SQLite database because it thinks the external storage is already mounted while the internal storage (SD Card) is still mounting which makes the app thinks the images are no longer there.

***Is there anyway to check the internal storage to see if it's ready after the phone reboots?***

I've tried the BOOT_COMPLETED, but it didn't seem to help at all since the internal storage is still mounting...

If someone can help me or point me to the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED) intent and this will tell you when the SD Card has been mounted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and help.  Would you mind to give me an example or some code?   How come it says " External media is present and mounted at its mount point"   Thanks

Comment: I've tried the code, and it did show up my toast message saying the SD Card is mounted.  It did help with my problem somehow. However, it still didn't solve my problem.  The reason is the app starts deleting the image paths as soon as the phone boots up.